# How can one use Google Sites as a Wiki?

Tags: wiki, google-classic-sites

Is it possible to use Google Sites as a Wiki where everyone can edit without first asking for the owner to allow them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer myself. One can use it as a Public Wiki by using [this](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/sites/thread?tid=51f6140c83dbb1cf&hl=en) trick.

> 1. Create a Google Group so anyone can join: http://groups.google.com/groups/create?lnk=gcphp
> 2. Invite the Group to your Site as a collaborator using its email address, e.g. MyGroup@googlegroups.com
> 3. Put a link to your Google Group on your Site, preferably on your homepage or sidebar, and a notice inviting those who are interested to
>      join.
> 4. Now anyone who subscribes to your Group automatically gets to edit your Site too.